# TradingView Forward testing strategy error - filling multiple orders per bar rather than one

Tags: pine-script

When I backtest my strategy it will only execute one order at the close of the bar, but when I let the strategy run in real-time it will execute multiple orders (sometimes 3,4,5 orders per bar). How do I stop this from happening so it only places ONE order per bar when forward testing?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `calc_on_every_tick = true` in your `strategy()` call, and set Pyramiding to `1` in the strategy's "Properties".

Answer (score 0):

I would consider `varip` variables that can store information within the same bar.

```
varip int traded = 0

if barstate.isnew
    traded := 0 

// === STRATEGY - LONG POSITION EXECUTION ===
if (MBS == 1)
    if traded == 0
        strategy.entry(id = "Buy", long = true, qty=orderSize) // use function or simple condition to decide when to get in
        traded := 1

// === STRATEGY - Close POSITION EXECUTION ===
if (MSS == 1)
    if traded == 0 
        strategy.close_all(when=MSS == 1)
        traded := 1
```

See more information [here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/ppQxBISk-Using-varip-variables-PineCoders/).